# "unrecognized selector" on "Save" button?

Tags: objective-c, unrecognized-selector

could you help me to understand an error? my project is a modalController that appears and let the user save a new text in a mutableArray.
I receive this error from the debugger :

> 2011-07-21 16:53:52.362 aeffa[18089:207] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b042d0

I checked the code but i can't see what's wrong : the "cancel" button works fine, but the "save" button launches the error. Here's my code :

```
            - (void)viewDidLoad {
                [super viewDidLoad];

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                         target:self
                                                         action:@selector(cancel:)] autorelease];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                                                           target:self 
                                                           action:@selector(save:)] autorelease];

            }
```

and the methods :

```
            - (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }

            - (IBAction) save:(id)sender{
                Website *newSite = [[Website alloc]init];
                NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc ]initWithString:url.text];

                newSite.websiteURL = newURL;
                newSite.websiteTitle = titre.text;
                newSite.websiteDesc = descr.text;

                [tabWebSites addObject:newSite];
                [newURL release];
                [newSite release];
            }
```

Thanks

Paul

Comment: How do you initialize `tabWebSites `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `tabWebSites` is actually an `NSArray` object.. which doesn't have a `addObject:` method. Make sure it's `NSMutableArray` (you probably allocate it as a `NSArray`, even if it might be declared as `NSMutableArray`).

Comment: Thanks, well there was a warning on it, i changed it thanks, but i still have the error : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e16e00' ... i use : modal.tabWebSites = self.tabWebsites; in RootVC, and the code above (my first post) in ModalVC. Do you know what i could do to find the bug?

Comment: Since you're setting it from RootVC you need to check how it's initialized in the RootVC class. Otherwise you can just set the tabWebsites from ModalVC as a `mutableCopy` of the tabWebsites from RootVC (e.g: if the property of modal.tabWebSites is `retain` you might call `modal.tabWebSites = [[self.tabWebsites mutableCopy] autorelease];`). Although, creating a mutableCopy might not work well with your code (in case you want the RootVC tabWebsites to be modified as well)

Comment: `RootViewController:43`: `self.tabWebsites = mutArray;//[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutArray];` (commented what was previously there)